# Getting List Of all sprints start and End Date in Azure Devops into my database?

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops

I have .net code which can call a query in Azure Devops and connect to my database.

Can I get list of sprints and their respective start and end dates into the query?

If this is not possible - is there any way I can get the list of sprints and their start and end dates into my database?

I can use PowerBI, Power Apps, SQL Server and C#. Can anyone suggest a solution using these tools?

Comment: Here is a document on the apis that you are interested in -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Comment: Hi Prasad, Does my answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could [connect to Analytics data by using the Power BI OData feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/access-analytics-power-bi?view=azure-devops#access-the-analytics-odata-feed), and then select "**Iterations**" query to get a list of sprints and their respective start and end dates. Also [remove unnecessary columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/choose-remove-columns).
[image]

Comment: Hi @edward-han-msft I am trying to connect to Azure DevOps using oData feed and getting the below error. I am able to pull data using Analytics View without any issues and my user has access to Analytics on the Team Project.

access_denied: AADSTS650053: The application 'Microsoft Power Query for Excel' asked for scope 'user_impersonation' that doesn't exist on the resource 'a4ce0e36-87e6-4227-bad6-bad83309a7c9'. Contact the app vendor.
Trace ID: 553717b9-66ff-48a7-ad85-261f26296200
Correlation ID: ff6e41ca-50c9-4d0a-b570-af216986b9ed
Timestamp: 2023-05-19 07:08:55Z.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use direct connection available in power-BI for azure dev ops boards. check details in the link below
[click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops)